# Ruby on rails: nested attribute form doesn't show up

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am working on Rails 3.1.1.rc3 and I have 2 classes as shown below.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

In my form:

```
<%= form_for(@customer) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name,:class=>'textbox' %>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :orders do |order_form| %>   
    <div class="field">
       <%= order_form.label :number %><br />
       <%= order_form.text_field :number, :class=>'textbox' %>
   </div>  
  <%end%>

<%end%>
```

When it renders, the first part of the form (for customer) shows up, but the second part (for order) doesn't. Any pointers are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone who is interested, this is a very good article.[link here](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things. First fields_for basically iterates over customer.orders so if there are no orders you'll get no output. If you just want some blank fields for users to input order details you'd typically stick

```
@customer.orders.build
```

In your controller. Secondly, `fields_for` is very similar to `form_for`, you need to use <%= for it too

Answer (score 1):

add

```
<%= f.fields_for :orders do |order_form| %>
```

instead of

```
<% f.fields_for :orders do |order_form| %>
```

Edit: have a look at [how fields_for is defined](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) (there are examples there)

Comment: This is the right answer. In rails 3 you have to put = to helpers that generate any kind of output, like form_for, fields_for etc.

Comment: Just tried. The second form doesn't show up either. But that's a good points. Thanks. Edited my question.